# INSERT not working when selection value is -1

Tags: php, html

I have problem, that if I not select any item from selection list, they not inserting element in my DB.

I put some come, that if I select value -1 from list, which is `------------`, then they should make it NULL in that field.

There is my code.

```
<p>
<?php
              if ($_POST['fk_KOMANDAid_KOMANDA'] == '-1') {
              $_POST['fk_KOMANDAid_KOMANDA'] = NULL;}
?>
        <label class="field" for="fk_KOMANDAid_KOMANDA">Komanda<?php echo in_array('fk_KOMANDAid_KOMANDA', $required) ? '<span> *</span>' : ''; ?></label>
        <select id="fk_KOMANDAid_KOMANDA" name="fk_KOMANDAid_KOMANDA">
            <option value="-1">---------------</option>
            <?php
                $kom = $asmuoObj->getkomanda();
                foreach($kom as $key => $val) {
                    $selected = "";
                    if(isset($data['fk_KOMANDAid_KOMANDA']) && $data['fk_KOMANDAid_KOMANDA'] == $val['id']) {
                            $selected = " selected='selected'";}
                    echo "<option{$selected} value='{$val['id']}'>{$val['pavadinimas']}</option>";}
            ?>
        </select>
</p>
```

This is INSERT function.

```
public function insertkomanda($data) {
        $query = "  INSERT INTO {$this->komanda_lentele}
                                (
                                    `pavadinimas`,
                                    `sutrumpinimas`,
                                    `ikurimo_data`,
                                    `svetaines_adresas`,
                                    `fk_VALSTYBEid_VALSTYBE`,
                                    `fk_RUNGTYNESid_RUNGTYNES`
                                ) 
                                VALUES
                                (
                                    '{$data['pavadinimas']}',
                                    '{$data['sutrumpinimas']}',
                                    '{$data['ikurimo_data']}',
                                    '{$data['svetaines_adresas']}',
                                    '{$data['fk_VALSTYBEid_VALSTYBE']}',
                                    '{$data['fk_RUNGTYNESid_RUNGTYNES']}'
                                )";
        mysql::query($query);
    }
```

When I press SUBMIT, then nothing happens, data not intserted in my DB. Should insert with `fk_KOMANDAid_KOMANDA` eaquls NULL.

Comment: Show your query and how you execute it as well. This code isn't enough.

Comment: I just updated question, please check it.

Comment: I think you are not selecting, what you are sending in data. Check the select box name attribute is `fk_KOMANDAid_KOMANDA` and not in insert query.

Comment: The problem is, if I select something from `fk_KOMANDAid_KOMANDA` list, the everything is good, but if I select value -1, which is `---------------`, then new element in my DB not inserted.

Comment: "Should insert with fk_KOMANDAid_KOMANDA eaquls NULL."  I don't see how it can,fk_KOMANDAid_KOMANDA is not a column namer a value in your insert.  Is {$data['pavadinimas']} supposed to be {$data[' fk_KOMANDAid_KOMANDA']} ?

Comment: that aside, what is your database structure like and what datatype are your inserts

Comment: fk_KOMANDAid_KOMANDA datatype alfanum